# WPF CollectionViewSource: combination SortDescription and GroupDiscription

Tags: sorting, datagrid, group-by

I've got a Collection which gets a `Sort` and a `GroupDescription`. The `GroupDescription` have a higher priority than the `SortDescription`. Is it possible to change this?

```xml
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Items}">

        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="Context.Number" Direction="Ascending"  />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="type"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>

    </CollectionViewSource>
```

thanks a lot.